# Starting a .jar GUI file using Linux

Tags: linux, debian, java, raspberry-pi, embedded

So I have Raspberry Pi running Debian and I also have a .jar program that has a GUI for Point-of-Sale System. So how do you configure Linux to start the x window system without displaying a full desktop environment and just display the .jar in a full screen window. (I want to make it less resource hungry and I want it to look more professional as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reformulate your question with proper header. The conceptual problem is start some gui app using only x windows system without desktop environment.

Also, if you won't find a solution, I can suggest you to use minimalistic window manager instead of full desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

try not booting x and run java filename.jar and see what happens,

then try booting x and make a start up to java filename.jar and see what happens

just try different things until you find something you like

Thank You

Larry Hyman

PS:

When I start my Linux Mint Machine, at Grub prompt, I choose recovery mode, get a recovery mode menu, and choose: drop to root shell

this gives me a command prompt, no x and I do not have to edit any config files, I reboot with "reboot" and choose a normal boot